# How can I work when I have a dollar sign in my header on SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite, dollar-sign

I'm working with SQLite and want to formulate a condition. Unfortunately, the huge file that I am working with has a dollar sign in the header.

You can download the file on the following link: http://www.portaldatransparencia.gov.br/downloads/servidores.asp#getC
[select 2017, then september and open the file named "20170930_Remuneracao"]

So I try to identify the header when I am tipping the "where" condition, but the dollar sign doesn't allow SQLite to identify properly the name of the header:

```
select *
from 20170930_Remuneracao
WHERE ABATE-TETO(R$) >= 1
```

Comment: Sorry, but not how Stack Overflow works. All relevant content has to be here, in the question itself. We don't go somewhere else to dig through to find a file and then open it. If the majority of the content is off-site, and that off-site location is unavailable for some reason, the question has zero value to a future reader here, and questions without future value don't belong here. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: You don't need the file to answer the question...

Comment: Read the review history. The code in the question wasn't there when I posted that comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just [quote](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) the table/column names:

```
SELECT * FROM "20170930_Remuneracao" WHERE "ABATE-TETO(R$)" >= 1;
```

Comment: Not sure why down-voted, but this is the answer given the OP's example SELECT statement.